# AWS: How to invoke a lambda when any resource is created

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to more effectively manage the resources we create in our AWS accounts and I would like to start by attaching a lambda or many lambdas whenever a resource is created. At a minimum, I need to tag the resources because we simply can't count on people to do it at all, much less correctly.

For example: I can get an event anytime an object is deleted in S3 but that isn't what I want; I want to know when a bucket it created; either through the console of a CFT or the CLI

The closest thing I can see is CloudFormation events man be monitored. We do a lot of stack creation of resources but not always so this isn't good enough. And, in any event, I would need to know all the resources that were created with that stack which [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-cloudformation-create-request) doesn't make clear if I could even get

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Have you looked at the [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) service?

Comment: Did you consider trying aws cloudtail you can use it to log any aws activity through console, api or cli and then deliver it to cloudwatch which finally result into your lambda function execution

Answer (score 1):

CloudTrail tracks user activity and API usage and generates CloudTrail Trails. Trails have Data Events.

CloudTrail Data Events can be passed directly to a Lambda function for processing (and/or S3 and/or CloudWatch).

In my own case we store CloudTrail Events in a S3 bucket but also pass them to a Lambda function that applies a billing tag to all new resources created in the account.

[GorillaStack Autotag](https://github.com/GorillaStack/auto-tag) might be a good starting point as a reference for the function.